# how to convert normal jsonfile to arrayofobject json file using nodejs and import to cloud firestore database

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

how to convert normal jsonfile to arrayofobject json file using nodejs and import to cloud firestore database

From Format Json Structure

```
 {
        "messages1": {
            "1585135109814test": {

                "Group_Desc": "Test",
                "Members": [{
                    "User_Profile_Pic": null,
                    "User_Id": "123",
                    "User_Name": "Vvvv"
                }, {
                    "User_Name": "Sss",
                    "User_Profile_Pic": "",
                    "User_Id": "456"
                }, {
                    "User_Name": "Rrr",
                    "User_Profile_Pic": "",
                    "User_Id": "789"
                }]
}
}
```

To Format Json Structure

```
[
  {
    "User_Name": "Rrr",
    "User_Profile_Pic": "",
    "User_Id": "789"
  },
  {
    "User_Name": "Sss",
     "User_Profile_Pic": "",
      "User_Id": "456"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) and loop over the Members array.

```js
const json = {
    "messages1": {
        "1585135109814test": {

            "Group_Desc": "Test",
            "Members": [{
                "User_Profile_Pic": null,
                "User_Id": "123",
                "User_Name": "Vvvv"
            }, {
                "User_Name": "Sss",
                "User_Profile_Pic": "",
                "User_Id": "456"
            }, {
                "User_Name": "Rrr",
                "User_Profile_Pic": "",
                "User_Id": "789"
            }]
        }
    }
}

const db = firebase.firestore();
const batch = db.batch();

const members = json['messages1']['1585135109814test']['Members'];
const membersRef = db.collection('members');

members.forEach((member) => {
    const doc = membersRef.doc(member.id);
    delete member.id; // do if you need to
    batch.set(doc, member);
});

// Commit the batch
batch.commit().then(function () {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just want to format the particular json to `array of objects`. If so and if I understand your question correctly, you can do it like this:

```js
var data = { "messages1": { "1585135109814test": { "Group_Desc": "Test", "Members": [{ "User_Profile_Pic": null, "User_Id": "123", "User_Name": "Vvvv" }, { "User_Name": "Sss", "User_Profile_Pic": "", "User_Id": "456" }, { "User_Name": "Rrr", "User_Profile_Pic": "", "User_Id": "789" }]}}};

var result = Object.entries(data).map(([k,v])=> Object.values(v)[0].Members.flat().filter(elem=>elem.User_Profile_Pic!=null)).flat();

console.log(result);
```

I'm taking `entries` of your json data then mapping it(with the given logic), 
and once the data is received, I'm flattening it using `flat()`. If you don't need, you can omit it.